# Swift: UTF-8 characters on URL

Tags: swift, macos, url, encoding, utf-8

I want to search some google translation through a web view on my OS X app made by Swift. For that, I need to put chinese characters on the link but it doesn't work. I tried encoding like what I read on stack overflow (here is my code):

```
var word = "是"   
var wordencoded = word.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
var url = "https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/\(wordencoded)"
self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(url))
```

But still it doesn't work. If you even know how to put it directly like this without encoding it would be nice because google translate handle well when you just put chinese or other utf-8 characters on the link.

And how can I handle the errors because when I do an error it suddenly crash and it's really annoying. If I need to handle errors, I just want to do nothing or print in the console that it didn't work.

Comment: There is a space between `word` and `encoded`. Could that be why?

Comment: Isnt it supposed to be `self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(url))`

Comment: oh sorry corrected it. But still have the problem